# Copy A Texture to PixelBuffer (CVPixelBufferRef)

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, textures, avassetwriter

I am using an API which only gives me the integer id of the texture object, and I need to pass that texture's data to AVAssetWriter to create the video.

I know how to create CVOpenGLESTexture object from pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef), but in my case I have to somehow copy the data of a texture of which only the id is available.

In other words, I need to copy an opengl texture to my pixelbuffer-based texture object. Is it possible? If yes then how?

In my sample code I have something like:

```
   void encodeFrame(Gluint textureOb)
    {

    CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer (NULL, [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor pixelBufferPool], &pixelBuffer[0]);

    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage (kCFAllocatorDefault, coreVideoTextureCache, pixelBuffer[0],
                                                          NULL, // texture attributes
                                                          GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                          GL_RGBA, // opengl format
                                                          (int)FRAME_WIDTH,
                                                          (int)FRAME_HEIGHT,
                                                          GL_BGRA, // native iOS format
                                                          GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                          0,
                                                          &renderTexture[0]);


    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer[pixelBuffernum], 0);

//Creation of textureOb is not under my control. 
//All I have is the id of texture. 
//Here I need the data of textureOb somehow be appended as a video frame. 
//Either by copying the data to pixelBuffer or somehow pass the textureOb to the Adaptor.

    [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer[0] withPresentationTime:presentationTime];

    }
```

Thanks for tips and answers.

P.S. `glGetTexImage` isn't available on iOS.

**Update:**

@Dr. Larson, I can't set the texture ID for API. Actually I can't dictate 3rd party API to use my own created texture object.

After going through the answers what I understood is that I need to:

1- Attach pixelbuffer-associated texture object as color attachment to a texFBO. 
For each frame:

2- Bind the texture obtained from API

3- Bind texFBO and call drawElements

What am I doing wrong in this code?

P.S. I'm not familiar with shaders yet, so it is difficult for me to make use of them right now.

**Update 2:**
With the help of Brad Larson's answer and using the correct shaders solved the problem. I had to use shaders which are an essential requirement of Opengl ES 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reading back data from OpenGL ES on iOS, you basically have two routes: using `glReadPixels()`, or using the texture caches (iOS 5.0+ only).

The fact that you just have a texture ID and access to nothing else is a little odd, and limits your choices here. If you have no way of setting what texture to use in this third-party API, you're going to need to re-render that texture to an offscreen framebuffer to extract the pixels for it either using `glReadPixels()` or the texture caches. To do this, you'd use an FBO sized to the same dimensions as your texture, a simple quad (two triangles making up a rectangle), and a passthrough shader that will just display each texel of your texture in the output framebuffer.

At that point, you can just use `glReadPixels()` to pull your bytes back into the the internal byte array of your CVPixelBufferRef or preferably use the texture caches to eliminate the need for that read. I describe how to set up the caching for that approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544293/where-is-the-official-documentation-for-cvopenglestexture-method-types/9574798#9574798), as well as how to feed that into an AVAssetWriter. You'll need to set your offscreen FBO to use the CVPixelBufferRef's associated texture as a render target for this to work.

However, if you have the means of setting what ID to use for this rendered texture, you can avoid having to re-render it to grab its pixel values. Set up the texture caching like I describe in the above-linked answer and pass the texture ID for that pixel buffer into the third-party API you're using. It will then render into the texture that's associated with the pixel buffer, and you can record from that directly. This is what I use to accelerate the recording of video from OpenGL ES in my GPUImage framework (with the `glReadPixels()` approach as a fallback for iOS 4.x).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, please have a look at my 'update' part of the question.

Comment: @Usman.3D - If you can't provide the ID to use for the texture, and you have no access to the time when the texture is rendered, you'll need to re-render it to an offscreen FBO to extract the color bytes for it. You can then use either of the approaches I describe: glReadPixels() to pull from the FBO, or a bound texture paired with the texture caches for a faster capture of the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr. Larson. Highly appreciate your help. I'm coding for what you just mentioned.

Comment: Dr. Larson, I need your valuable comment again. Please refer to the update2. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Usman.3D - Where is your glReadPixels() in the above? If you're not reading pixels back using that, you need to have set up your texture cache correctly and to have bound the relevant texture to your render FBO. Make sure you're following all of the setup steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550297/faster-alternative-to-glreadpixels-in-iphone-opengl-es-2-0/9704392#9704392 and that you're using the same OpenGL ES context for texture upload and your texture cache.

Comment: @Dr. Larson, I did setup the texture cache but I did not include the code of that in the above. I'm going to include that in the update.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Larson. The technique of attaching the texture to a textureFBO worked. I just had to use correct shaders which you had described in another answer of yours. Highly appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's rather unfortunate that glGetTexImage isn't ios.  I struggled with that when I implemented my CCMutableTexture2D class for cocos2d.

### Caching the image before pushing to the gpu

If you take a look into the source you'll notice that in the end I kept the pixel buffer of the image cached into my CCMutableTexture2D class instead of the normal route of discarding it after it's pushed to the gpu.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2449

### Using FBO's and glReadPixels

Sadly, I think this approach might not be appropriate for you since you're creating some kind of video with the texture data and holding onto every pixel buffer that we've cached eats up a lot of memory.  Another approach could be to create an FBO on the fly in order to use glReadPixels to populate your pixel buffer.  I'm not too sure how successful that approach will be but a good example was posted here:
[Read texture bytes with glReadPixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863416/read-texture-bytes-with-glreadpixels)

Comment: If you're going to be creating the texture anyway, there is a much faster way to access the bytes behind it as of iOS 5.0. You can use the texture caches to directly read and write the backing bytes behind a texture, as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550297/faster-alternative-to-glreadpixels-in-iphone-opengl-es-2-0/9704392#9704392 . This is a direct memory access that does not rely on `glReadPixels()` or `glTexImage2D()`.