# Pixel access with glGetTexImage()?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, sdl-2

I have a problem with OpenGL and `glGetTexImage()`.

I want to get the pixels of a texture that I've created before with
code like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0, 
    GL_RGBA, 
    width,
    height,
    0, 
    GL_RGB, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
    someRandomPixels);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

I'm using SDL2.

After I loaded that texture I tried to get the pixels of this texture
in a GLuint* pixels pointer which I declared as follows:

```
GLuint* pixels = new GLuint[256*256*4];
```

the size of this image was 256x256 pixels.

I got the pixel data by using

```
GLuint* Textur::getPixelsOfTextur(GLuint textur, int width, int height, int numChannels)
{
    GLuint* pixels=new GLuint[width*height*numChannels];
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textur);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, pixels);
     return pixels;
}
```

Where "numChannels" is 4 for RGBA and 3 for RGB

Now my problem is that I really have no clue how to address Pixel p(x,y) correctly since the size of my array is 4 times bigger than the pixel count and every time I use a smaller size visual studios throws an error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x5ED71FCE (opengl32.dll) in sdl_opengl_Frameworktest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x09C33000.
```

Also, is it possible to get those data in a 2D array?

Comment: Although it is not because of the reason I commented, but for people searching for "OpenGL texture to image", who must notice glGetTexImage isn't available in OpenGL ES(according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11947751)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of the array in bytes is 1048576 bytes (`256 * 256 * 4 * sizeof(GLuint)`). This is, because every color channel of a single pixel is stored in a separate `GLuint` with a size of 4 bytes (`sizeof(GLuint) == 4`). So the size of each pixel is 16 bytes because of 4 color channels per pixel and `sizeof(GLuint)` for each color channel.

Probably it will be sufficient to store every color in an `GLubyte`. Then the size of the array will be 262144 bytes (`256 * 256 * 4 * sizeof(GLubyte)`)

```
GLubyte* pixels = new GLubyte[256*256*4];

glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Regardless if you use `GLuint` or `GLubyte`, the colors of a single pixel can be accessed like this:

```
GLuint r, g, b, a; // or GLubyte r, g, b, a;

size_t x, y; // line and column of the pixel

size_t elmes_per_line = 256 * 4; // elements per line = 256 * "RGBA"

size_t row = y * elmes_per_line;
size_t col = x * 4;

r = pixels[row + col]; 
g = pixels[row + col + 1]; 
b = pixels[row + col + 2]; 
a = pixels[row + col + 3];
```

If you want to calculate a gray scale value from the `r`, `g` , `b` values, the this can be don like this:

```
GLubyte gray = (GLubyte)((r + g + b) / 3.0);
```

Another popular formula can be found at [**Luma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)):

```
GLubyte gray = (GLubyte)(r*0.2126 + g*0.7152 + b*0.0722);
```

Replace the color RGB channels by the grayscale:

```
pixels[row + col]     = gray; 
pixels[row + col + 1] = gray; 
pixels[row + col + 2] = gray;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this tomorrow and tell you how it worked

Comment: Now that I implemented it like you told me erveything works. Thank you! You are a time and life saver

Comment: Just one further question. I tried to replace every pixel with it's gray pixel by calculating it's average. The resulting texture seems a bit dark compared to ImageJ results. I know that that's not C++ but maybe you have an idea

Comment: sry to bother you again and if you don't know it it dosnt matter, but do you now an answer to my second question i asked in the comments?

Comment: thank you do i need to uncheck this mark so that u can alter it? I'm relatively new here. I just do it

Comment: Yup the luma version worked just fine. Thank you again, kind man! I let the check mark checked now. You are the best!